# Modify Widgets in non-GUI thread in Qt?

Tags: performance, qt, qthread

Suppose I have multi-threaded my Application. Then as per Qt philosophy you cannot even modify the properties of `Widgets` added in GUI. Say an object of class `Not_GUI` has been moved to another `QThread`, then it illegal to call `button1->SetEnabled(false);` (`button1` is a `QPushButton` added in GUI) in a function of `Not_GUI`.

Currently my application has many GUI `widgets` (like QLabel, QLineEdit, etc) & since all their `events` are processed in only 1 thread the application hangs for a while due to the enormous painting activity.
Is there a way by which I can somehow distribute some of the workload of `Widgets` to various thread's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first example use signals and slots. `QWidget::setEnabled()` is a slot. create a signal `modifyWidgetEnableState(bool)` and connect to the slot. trigger the signal instead of using the direct method call.

> the application hangs for a while due to the enormous painting activity

Are these widgets Qt build in? If yes I doubt the hang is due to the painting. Are these widgets yours? Then you may be doing too much processing in your subclassed event handlers.
The first thing to do will be to try to improve the performance of whatever you doing, the second thing will be to move the heavy processing in threads, and (*again*) use signals and slots to communicate with the widgets.

EDIT:
Assume o1 and o2 and are moved to different threads t1 and t2.

Whenever `o2->slot()` is executed as a normal function call then it is the ***calling thread*** which is executing `slot()`. Remember, `slot()` after all is a normal C++ method. Whenever a signal `sig()` connected to `slot()` is triggered, then it is ***the receiver thread*** which is executing `slot()`. So choose either one or the other, otherwise you will be subject to race conditions.

Comment: regarding the SIGNAL & SLOT ans:
Is the processing in the SLOT done on the GUI thread or the thread in which the SIGNAL was emitted?

Yes the widgets are Qt built only I havent created any custom widget. Widgets like QLabel, QLineEdit are used. The hang is due to the painting only because if I dont add that QGridLayout to the GUI then there is no hang. By hang I mean that the App does not respond to the clicks & shows (not responding) & along with the circle cursor in Windows 7.

I have not handled any events myself. Everything is handled by Qt's functions.

Comment: if `o1` and `o2` and are ***moved to*** different threads `t1` and `t2`, `o1` trigger a signal, then the slot of `o2` will be executed by thread `t2`. If you directly call `o2->slot()` then it will be executed like any normal function call. But this is broken multithreading.

Comment: The hang is not due to painting.Definitely not. It is due to your functions making heavy processing in the main thread, which prevent display paint code to be executed.

Comment: "If you directly call o2->slot() then it will be executed like any normal function call."
Do you mean that slot() will be executed by thread t1 on the assumption that o2->slot() was called by a function in thread t1?

"But this is broken multithreading." so you mean that what I said in last line is a wrong method & I should use SIGNAL & SLOT?

Comment: Regarding hang let me tell you the details:
I have a function in the Main Window class which adds 10,000's of QLineEdit & QLabel in a QGridLayout in my Main Window.
At the last line of that function I have added a qDebug << "Function Ended!".
When I run the application I am getting "Function Ended!" printed almost immediately.
After about 15 more secs, the RAM for my process stays constant & processor is 25% constant (that means only GUI thread is working).
Now the question is which event is taking that much processing?
My guess is that it is the PaintEvent.
What do you say?

Comment: you get "Function Ended!" instantly because the actions of your main window class are effectively executed at `app.exec();`. Before hand they are just queued for processing. Does your app really have 10000 line edits??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26227/discussion-between-cad-coding-and-umnyobe)

Comment: Just replace all your QLabels and LineEdits with QTableWidget. Print variable names at top of the table. Do yo really need it that bad to see *x1 ... *xn  near all LineEdits? If you need it THAT bad, Just do it with QTextEdit or something, where user inputs equations as they are, and you parse them. Would be more easier then painting thousands of widgets

Answer (score 0):

As you say, Qt requires that all widget painting be done in the main thread.  There's no way around that.  You *can* paint into a `QImage` in a separate thread, then simply draw the image to the widget in its `paintEvent()`.  However, first bear in mind that this takes extra memory for all the buffer images.  Also, if you're able to do that then it might well be easier to take the same approach without threading.  In general your goal should be to do as little work as possible inside `paintEvent()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can call any functions to modify your ui from another thread via `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()` and to run some function in a separate thread you can use `QtConcurrent::run` (i use it with `QFutureWatcher`). Probably not canonical Qt way, but works for me just fine, if i don't want to create my own QThread::run for every function